# Best way to handle null task inside async method?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

What is the best way to handle a `null` task inside an `async` method?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly Task task;
   public MyClass(Task task) { this.task = task; }

   public async Task Execute()
   {
      if (task == null)
      {
         await Task.Yield(); /* Is this the best way? */
         return;
      }
      await task;
   }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd say `public MyClass(Task task){if (task == null)throw new ArgumentNullException("task");..}`

Comment: Just don't accept null tasks. BTW, what *are* you trying to do? Wrapping a task and adding an execute method is *very* suspicious and possibly a code smell - trying to "control" when a task starts or executes, when there's no reason to. A Task itself *is* a class that abstracts when its delegate starts and executes, you don't need to add another class on top of it to do the same.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the best practice for dealing with a potentially null task inside an async method. For the purpose of this discussion, let's assume that I've inherited a method that may allow null tasks and adding a null check in the constructor is not an option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to handle `null` tasks. Simply null check it:

```
public async Task Execute()
{
   if (task != null)
   {
       await task;
   }
}
```

Or even better, simply return the task since you're not adding anything after the `await`:

```
public Task Execute()
{
   return task;
}
```

If you want to return a completed task instead of `null` you can use `Task.FromResult`:

```
public Task Execute()
{
   return task ?? Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

Comment: "Task.FromResult(false)" works great when you have an overridable method that you can't make strictly abstract. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: Now that the Elvis operator is so common (`.?`) -- I have an extension method that uses this approach to make sure those await calls always work: `public static Task<T> NullSafe<T>(this Task<T> task) => task ?? Task.FromResult(default(T));` -- so you can write code like `var x = await (someObject?.DoTheThing()).NullSafe();` (Keep in mind, because of the way that the Elvis operator works, the parenthesis are significant in this statement.)

Comment: "Task.CompletedTask" is an option, too

Answer (score 16):

Most asynchronous code is cleaner if tasks are never null. Instead of a null task, use `Task.FromResult(0)` or some such construct.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly Task task;
  public MyClass(Task task) { this.task = task ?? Task.FromResult(0); }

  public async Task ExecuteAsync()
  {
    await task;
  }
}
```

Or, if that's really all your `ExecuteAsync` is doing:

```
public Task ExecuteAsync()
{
  return task;
}
```

Note that the task is *already running* when the constructor is called, which makes the method name `ExecuteAsync` a misnomer. If you want the task to *start* when `ExecuteAsync` is called, then what you really want to store is a `Func<Task>`:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly Func<Task> func;
  public MyClass(Func<Task> func) { this.func = func ?? () => Task.FromResult(0); }

  public async Task ExecuteAsync()
  {
    await func();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to handle a null task inside an async method?

Best practices typically include not allowing null parameters (unless the business rules require them).

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly Task _task;

   public MyClass(Task task) 
   { 
     if (task == null)
     {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
     }

     this._task = task; 
   }

   public async Task Execute()
   {
      await this._task;
   }
}
```